# Приложение (файл apk), с Google AdMob рекламой, скачанный не с Google Play (а просто с сайта), будет показывать рекламу и зарабатывать на ней?

Tags: android, admob

Файл (приложение) apk, с официально зарегистрированной, встроенной и работающей (приносящий доход) Google AdMob рекламой, выложенный просто для скачивания на обычном сайте (не в Google Play) будет так же (после установки) показывать рекламу и приносить доход как и если бы это приложение реализовывалось через Google Play?

И можно ли так вообще делать, если сотрудничаешь с Google Play и Google AdMob рекламой?

Comment: Будет работать, пока приложение остаётся в маркете. Когда вас там забанят - отключится и реклама. Пока не забанили - установленное не из PlayMarket приложение мало чем отличается от приложения из любого другого магазина.Чтобы не беспокоиться об отключении рекламы после бана в GooglePlay - не используйте AdMob. Возьмите любую другую рекламу, MoPub, например.

Comment: На современных устройствах может блокировать установку не из PlayMarket или как минимум выдавать неприятное сообщение что это опасное приложение и тому подобное, ну а если все же установить все будет работать так же